# Setting up priorities for the team of developers

Tags: prioritization

Let's say we need to create a new system for internal use.

You will have to set up priorities for the team of developers. To start using this new system, the product could be released with 6 elements only.
What will be the priority of each element according to your personal criteria?

Please list the priorities by order of importance from 1 to 10, where 1 means highest priority and 10 means lowest priority.

List:

- Design
- Functionality of each page
- System speed
- Usage of new technologies
- Bug free code
- Access from all devices
- Full description    of all features
- Centralized system
- Intuitive layout and usability
- Other (please clarify)

Note: You need to specify all 10, and any others you consider important (for example AB testing).

Please explain your reasoning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework.

Answer (score 3):

Your original question cannot be answered meaningfully outside of your organization because you are missing a *prioritization process*. You can use any documented, repeatable process that works for your team and your organization.

Once you have a process, you could then use techniques like [relative weighting](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/tools/relative-weighting) or [theme screening](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/tools/theme-screening) that support your process. However, you must define a process *before* you can select an appropriate tool or technique to implement that process.

Answer (score 2):

Surveying for opinions about how to prioritize this list would product interesting but not very useful results.  You need to score each of these based on benefits, costs, risks, and penalties, quantifying as much as you can, and then prioritizing based on the score.

Comment: I understand that. But as I'm a junior, trying to get useful advice around. So hypothetically without analysing the data, how would you prioritise based on your intuition.

Comment: David's point, I think, is that using "intuition" can produce a list of priorities but that list would not be useful since my intuition is likely to deliver a different priority list to your intuition, or David's or whomever's. Without objective analysis against which to judge the relative merits of one possible priority over another it is impossible to produce anything other than a subjective judgement, aka a "guess". So your guess would be as good as anyone elses. Furthermore, as stated it is not a Project Management issue and is thus off-topic for this site.